# REQUEST_FILENAME wrong value

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am experimenting problems in local with a specific dynamic URL of my website: **test.app/en/schools/stpauls**. In production it is working fine.

In my .htaccess I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The issue is that, REQUEST_FILENAME has the wrong value, this is **schools.php** instead of **schools**, so it thinks it is a real file so it doesn't enter to index.php, which it is my routing controller.

In addition, if I print the php INFO_VARIABLES I get this:

```
_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] /en/schools.php/stpauls
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /en/schools/stpauls
```

Why are they different? Shouldn't be the same?

In which moment is set the _SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] or where is it adding the .php extension to the REQUEST_FILENAME variable?

I am running Apache 2.4.23 on WAMPSERVER 3.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add that (on top) to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

Comment: Thank you very much Croises. It works now disabling the MultiViews